# CodeQL analysis TRAP import

Tags: github-actions, codeql

On CodeQL analysis, I faced the below issue with

```
Dataset codeql_databases/go/db-go has been finalized and does not support further TRAP import.
```

The `github/codeql-action/init` is used for the creation of database, as per the documentation this is actually not a database, but a directory that contains databases.

Tried cleaning up but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out like since the action is running on a self-hosted runner, and somehow the codeql_database got corrupted. Fixed this by clearing the codeql_database location and recreating this from initially as a result the database finalizes correctly now.